# ng-src not working for youtube embed video

Tags: angularjs

I have a small issue with youtube embed code:

`<iframe ng-src="{{ emedUrl }}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

In my controller,
`$scope.emedUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/<videId>";`

Embed code is not working.

Comment: Use $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(yourUrl) instead, dont forget injecting $sce

Comment: I have no idea how to use. Can you post a code snippet.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it fix your problem:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .filter('trustUrl', function ($sce) {
    return function(url) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
   };
});
```

And then in your frame:

```
<iframe ng-src="{{ emedUrl | trustUrl }}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed code like this in my controller as said by @ Mohsen

`$scope.embedUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+videoId);`

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see your comment and I posted my answer

Answer (score 0):

To allow third party url use `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl()`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <iframe ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-src="{{emedUrl}}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    {{emedUrl}}
    </div>



    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
        $scope.emedUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/nhvxtxBBJVc");
    });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```